Can / should I cope baseboard with a simple, squarish profile?
Complete novice here - I'm replacing all the baseboard in my home due to water damage. I decided to go with 7 1/4 high baseboards from Metrie with a simple flat profile to replace the existing 5 1/4 colonial style ones (wanted something that looked a little more modern).

https://www.metrie.com/products/moulding/1680238
However, mitering the inside corners has proved ... more challenging than expected. I've got one of those DeWalt 7 1/4 trim 20V mitre saws. Awesome little saw, the main issue is with the idiot who bought it thinking he could use its 8" cut sliding capacity to cut a 45 bevel with the base lying flat and it would come out perfectly straight.
I know I can't get around mitering the outside corners, but for the inside corners, is it possible to cope the joint? I saw videos on YouTube for coping, but they all seem to work best for complex curved profile boards - I'm having trouble visualizing how it would work for a baseboard that is essentially flat except for a small channel near the top.
Any recommendations (other than "buy a larger mitre saw or smaller baseboards, you dummy") or pointers toward resources / tutorials would be much appreciated - thank you!

tl; dr: you can cope this style too, same as curved profiles. It doesn't matter.
As you probably saw (heh) in the videos, the usual technique to cope inside miters is these two steps:

With a miter saw, cut the end at 45 degrees to expose the wood. I use a miter box - much less messy and noisy when working in the house.
With a coping saw, cut a 'reverse angle' along the junction of the face and wood. Angle the coping cut to make an edge, the exact angle isn't critical. 20 degrees or so is fine.

I would add another step:

With a fine file (flat and/or rounded), fine shape and dry-fit the coped edge. I have this nifty flat+curved combo diamond file, that's proven adequate for most shapes and makes a cleaner edge than a bastard or rat-tail file.

This cope-in-progress shows the general idea:

from https://www.justneedspaint.com/how-to-cope-baseboard-inside-corners/
While coping joints like this seems tedious, the result is a tight, no-gap joint even when the corner isn't square (and they almost never are.) It's worth doing even with a square profile like yours.
A couple of tips:

Cope first, then cut to length.
Only cope one end side of any piece. Plan ahead.

Keep in mind that it's nearly impossible to cope two ends and have the length come out right. Also, with extra length, if you goof up your cope you can start again.

Yes, you can cope that profile, it should look like this:

One other consideration is that walls are rarely 90 deg angles, so cutting your base board at 45 deg angle may not work. You can get a miter protractor that will tell you what the corner angle is and what angle to set your saw at.
